# How can I keep my robot character within the borders of a Plane?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am pretty new to Unity, and I am trying to do the following:

I have a robot character that runs around a field (plane with grass texture)
What is happening is the robot runs forward and goes on forever

I have tried using Colliders and Box meshes, but not sure where to put the C# code that checks colliderEnter, Stay and Exit.

Does Mesh and script go on the Plane or on the Robot?

Does anyone have a quick solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just getting started as well, but I did this following a tutorial the other day.

Add a cube, change its scale around so that it *contains* your field and perhaps a little out of it.  Turn off the `mesh renderer` for it so it is no longer visible.  Create a script - HitBoundary.cs - and add it as a component to your re-sized non-rendered cube.

In that file, add a handler for `OnTriggerExit`

```
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)    {
        // Destroy everything that leaves the trigger
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

Although you may not want to destroy it.

Why am I calling `OnTriggerExit`?  With the field/map/level/etc. contained INSIDE the cube, anything in play is colliding from the moment exits.  So we track when it exits the collision status and act on that to remove/replace/move/destroy/whatever the object that has left our playing field.

Comment: I have both the character (capsule Collider) and a Boundary with a Box Collider sized like I need.
I have 2 scripts. 
1. Makes the character walk forward
2. The one you recommended.

When I execute, The Box and the Capsule Colliders both get unchecked and the character just runs forever, like Forrest Gump LOL

Comment: @user5451365 - the relevant part of the tutorial i was working through - https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial/boundary?playlist=17147

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need to do is:

1. Add a box collider around the plane where you would like your boundaries to be.
2. Add a collider to the robot (I would suggest box or pill, but it could be anything, experiment!)
3. Since the robot is the one moving, I think the collision code belongs in the robot controller (See how to write collision code [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html))

It's going to look something like:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Collider robot = collision.collider;
        Debug.Log("Just hit the wall!")
    }
```

If you just want to have the robot stop when it hits the wall, you don't even need an `onCollisionEnter()` method -- the physics engine will do all of the work for you!

Comment: I have both the character (capsule Collider) and a Boundary with a Box Collider sized like I need.
I have 2 scripts. 
1. Makes the character walk forward
2. The one you recommended.

When I execute, The Box and the Capsule Colliders both get unchecked and the character just runs forever, like Forrest Gump LOL